# Force YouTube Embed to open in App on IOS/Android

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile, youtube, embed

I have several YouTube videos embedded on a webpage.  To be more specific, the page has one single iframe and links to several youtube videos - I use the target attribute to force these links to open within the iframe.

For users on mobile, I'd like the videos to open within the YouTube app (if they have it installed). This is the default behavior for YouTube links, however, it doesn't happen in my case because the links target the iframe so it just causes the video to embed on the page and then play within the browser.

My guess is the easiest way to do what I'm looking to do would be to use javascript to change the target attribute(s) just on mobile. However, I'm open to other ideas to achieve this as well.